# Running a simple Map-Reduce example

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I found an example that looks pretty simple from here:

https://github.com/jsoftbiz/mapreduce_1

I don't know how to run it? Can someone try and see how do we get this working? Is it a command prompt program?  Should we run a JAR? Should I make a package in Maven for it?

I do have Cloudera Hadoop,HBase installed locally and can do a `clusterstart` for that.

But Ok let's say I am given an example of a Map-Reduce like that above, How do I run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is download the zip on your local machine and then use maven to  build the jar file. I did a quick try and I was able to build the JAR fairly quickly as pom.xml is configured properly to build the jar:

[image]

Once jar is ready you just need to pass the jar file with file input (provided in zip as input.txt) and output parameters.

Comment: Thanks, what maven goal is used? Is it a maven install? or maven package? or something else? Sorry a Maven noob too